# jQuery position works on Localhost Cassini, jsFiddle, but always return 0 when IIS or IIS express

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis, cassini

I have a table which each row contain a time. The table should show the closest time of the day on top. For example, if the current time is 12:03 the first row on the table should be 12:00. Basically the table auto scroll depending on the time of the day.

I have a code that works fine when running in Visual Studio development environment (Cassini). The code also works in jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvirizarry/ZVNwt/5/), but when I install the code in the server or run it with IIS Express, the position always return 0. I do not understand why the jquery position doesn't work or return 0 when IIS or IIS express is used.

Below is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var tableID = $('.dcBooking')[0].id; //get the id of table.
var layerID = $('#' + tableID).parent().closest('div').attr('id'); //get the id of the div created by .Net

var currentdate = new Date();
var hour = currentdate.getHours();

var min = currentdate.getMinutes();
var mod = min % 10;
min = (min - mod); //Rounded to the closest previous 10 minutes

var id = getID(hour, min);
var timeTag = $('#' + id);

$('#' + layerID).animate({ scrollTop: timeTag.position().top }, 'slow');
});
```

Example of HTML:

```
<div id="id1" style="overflow-x:visible;overflow-y:scroll;height:350px;position:relative;">
<table class="dcBooking">           
<tr id="h08_00_0"><td>08:00</td><td>Joe</td></tr>
<tr id="h12_10_0"><td>12:10</td><td>John</td></tr>
              :
              :
<tr id="h17_00_0"><td>07_00</td><td>Anna</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I have run out of ideas why the code return a position when run in Cassini or jsFiddle, but it doesn't when installed on the server or run in IIS express. I thought about security issue, but it runs on my computer with Cassini, but not with IIS express, so I think must be some IIS set-up, but I don't know where to look in IIS. Can anyone point me out what or where to look or have an idea what could be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what is causing the problem, but I was able to make it work by adding a delay to the javascript. I thought that maybe waiting for load instead of document ready would be the solution, but it still did not work with $(window).load(). I added a delay of 300 milliseconds and the position is returning a value other than zero. In case somebody has a similar issue, here is what I did to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   setTimeout("setScrolling()", 300);

});

function setScrolling() {

    var currentdate = new Date();
    var hour = currentdate.getHours();

    var min = currentdate.getMinutes();
    var mod = min % 10;
    min = (min - mod); //Rounded to the closest previous 10 minutes

    var id = 'h' + hour + "_" + min;
    var timeTag = $('#' + id);


     $('#id1').animate({ scrollTop: timeTag.position().top }, 'slow');

 }
```